# c++ std::vector dont get raw data from subclass

Tags: c++11, vector

hey guys i have a problem with the std::vector and i need your help.
I am currently programming a rendering engine with the new vulkan api and i want to support different vertex layouts for different meshes.
The problem is that std::vector::data() doesnt return the raw data i need. Here are my Vertex structs:

```
struct Vertex 
{
};
struct VertexColor : public Vertex
{
public:
    VertexColor(Vec3f pos, Vec3f col) : position(pos), color(col) {}
    Vec3f position;
    Vec3f color;
};
```

This is what i actually have and works:

```
     std::vector<VertexColor> cubeVertexBuffer = {
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), Vec3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f  ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f   ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  ), Vec3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), Vec3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), Vec3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f  ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) }
};

uint32_t size = 8 * sizeof(VertexColor);
Vertex* vertices = (Vertex*)malloc(size);
memcpy(vertices, cubeVertexBuffer.data(), size);

std::vector<uint32_t> cubeIndexBuffer = { 1,2,0,  2,3,0,
                                          0,3,4,  3,7,4,
                                          5,1,4,  1,0,4,
                                          2,6,3,  6,7,3,
                                          5,6,1,  6,2,1,
                                          6,5,7,  5,4,7 };

Cube::cubeMesh = new Mesh(vertices, size, cubeIndexBuffer);
```

What i want:

```
    std::vector<Vertex> cubeVertexBuffer = {
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f ), Vec3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f  ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f   ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f  ), Vec3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f), Vec3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f ), Vec3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f  ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f ) },
        VertexColor{ Vec3f( -1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f ), Vec3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f ) }
};

std::vector<uint32_t> cubeIndexBuffer = { 1,2,0,  2,3,0,
                                          0,3,4,  3,7,4,
                                          5,1,4,  1,0,4,
                                          2,6,3,  6,7,3,
                                          5,6,1,  6,2,1,
                                          6,5,7,  5,4,7 };

Cube::cubeMesh = new Mesh(cubeVertexBuffer, cubeIndexBuffer);
```

As i mentioned i need the whole vertex data in a raw format contigously in memory for mapping to the gpu, but the .data() function with the std::vector doesnt return the "real data". I dont know how i can using inheritation with the std::vector to get the "raw data from the subclass" in it.
Hope you can help me!
Thanks

EDIT: I checked the memory and with the std::vector, where i put my VertexColor(..) data into it, it dont set any data in memory. Is it because the "Vertex" struct does not have any members?

Comment: Does Mesh have a constructor that takes two vectors?

Comment: Yes of course. This is the constructor i want:        Mesh(const std::vector<Vertex>& vertices, const std::vector<uint32_t>& indices); For the first version (with memcpy) i have of course another constructor with a pointer instead of the first std::vector and the size in bytes

Comment: Show the Mesh constructors, please. Prototypes, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, never inherit from std::vector. It is not recommended and probably bad practise.

Also have a look at Vec3f. Does it have any virtual methods or destructors? You might be sitting with more data in your classes than just the members you defined. The structures you use should be plain old c++ objects without any polymorphic properties (i.e. plain c-style structures).

Also, check your member byte alignment. You can remove all padding from structures with:

```
    #pragma pack(push)
    #pragma pack(1)
    struct ...
    {
        ...
    }
    #pragma pack(pop)
```

Let me know if you get it going.

Additionally `vector<Vertex>` and `vector<VertexColor>` are not comparable, since the individual elements have different sizes. In my experience the 3D APIs expect the data in a very specific format and you can't do it generically if the API does not already provide the format for you.

Slicing can also occur, as Jens suggests.

Comment: hello and thanks for your answer. I dont inherit from std::vector. What i actually mean is i have a vector with a <Vertex> in it but give it a <VertexColor> (which inherits from Vertex). So when i now try to use .data() on the vector with that setup i get crap and i dont know why. Vec3f does not have any virtual methods. Beside that if i using a std::vector with <VertexColor> (instead of vertex) everything works fine, but i want it to be generic

Comment: @SilvanHau If you want to be generic this usually implies templates. What happens is that you assign a VertexColor object to a Vertex object which copies only Vertex's members.

Answer (score 0):

What you are experiencing is called slicing. When you declare a `vector<Vertex>`, it will hold instances of Vertex. Each "cell" will be large enough for the data in Vertex. Since Vertex is a base-class of VertexColor, it is possible to assign a VertexColor object to a Vertex, but this will only copy the data members from Vertex. Vertex has no members, so what do you expect to be the content of a `vector<Vertex>`?

Inheritance is the wrong design approach in this case. From what I see, `Mesh` should be a template class `template<typename V> class Mesh<V>` to support different Vertex types, restricted to be a standard layout type (with `enable_if<is_standard_layout<V>::value, V, V>::type`).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, i kinda thought this. I wil try using a template :)

Comment: well, i found another solution without a template which fits my need. I am using now an intermediate "VertexBuffer" object which accepts std::vector<> with all vertex formats in my engine. Using this in the constructor of the mesh class allows me to pass the different std::vectors to it. Disadvantage: If i creating new vertex layouts i have to modify the "VertexBuffer" class, but this shouldnt be a big deal